# Add custom element as child of another custom element

Tags: javascript, html, coffeescript, custom-element

I've defined 2 custom elements and I want to be able to drag and drop one onto another and have the dropped one become the child of the first.

I haven't implemented the dragging yet, so at this point I've got one custom element's connectedCallback() creating the other custom element and attaching it to itself, but it doesn't work...

I get this error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'CustomElement': The result
>   must not have attributes

code (Sorry, it's CoffeeScript):

```html
class elementOne extends HTMLElement
    constructor: ->
        super()

class elementTwo extends elementOne
    constructor: ->
        super()

class elementThree extends elementOne
    constructor: ->
        super()
    connectedCallback: ->
        myElement = document.createElement('test-one')


customElements.define('test-one', elementTwo)
customElements.define('test-two', elementThree)
```

Am I trying to do something that custom elements are not allowed to do?

I am using JavaScript and do not want to use any libraries.

Comment: `Am I trying to do something that custom elements are not allowed to do?` It's difficult to say if you don't show us what you've done :)

Comment: Thanks guys, I've added the code. It's CoffeeScript. Don't shoot me.